# How to allocate hash power to an instance of bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, miner-configuration, cpu, regtest

I'm not sure if those questions were asked this way before but ...:

**Is it possible to allocate CPU resources/hash power to an instance of bitcoind run on regtest?If yes, how?**
Assuming I'm going to run 100 nodes on regtest, how can I run one node with 20% of total hashing power?

**Is CPU allocation hardcoded? If yes, where in the code?**

**If not possible by Bitcoin source code, is there a way to allocate CPU to a daemon, in general?**

By the way: I'm using Bitcoin Core 0.10.0.

Comment: Regtest doesn't really have hashpower - each node mints a block only when you tell it to. You could replicate the same thing by having a cronjob that triggers the creation of a block every so ofter.

Comment: @NickODell: Ok i see..or in case of selfish mining simulation and for mimicking hashpower distribution I could use a pool of 20 selfish miners out of 100 nodes for 20%, right?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi you can allocate CPU to a particular process if you're using linux/OS X with setting the priority of the process, called [niceness](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127312/what-does-a-niceness-value-of-mean).